# Is there a way to insert primary key into Table1 and Table2 before inserting a foreign key into Table 3 in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database where the data received would be in the form of a foreign key, so I would like to know if there is a method whereby the insertion of a foreign key will trigger the creation of the respective primary keys in the other tables. I know that in other databases such as MySQL, we can create `trigger`s with the `before` keyword to perform such an operation on the database, but `before` is not applicable in SQL Server.

Example Schema:

[image]

Steps trying to replicate:

1. Adding a `(ID,mobile)` foreign key pair into `Contact` table.
2. Adding the respective `ID` and `mobile` data into the respective tables.

Would there be any way to do this in SQL Server more efficiently than having to check every single relevant table for the presence of the primary keys?

Comment: You are at root saying you want to disable fk checks on insert to a specific table and that's not possible.

Comment: You can use INSTEAD OF trigger which will perform correct INSERTs when trying to insert into Contact.

Comment: Preferably you can create an sp for the purpose.

Comment: @P.Salmon I'm not looking to disable fk checks as I do need it for other queries, but what I meant was that if i were to attempt to insert (ID, mobile) into Contact, it would check the Ident and Phone table first, add the relevant data if missing, then add the row into Contact.

Comment: *...but before is not applicable in SQL Server*. Yes it is, if only you were to [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) about *Instead of* keyword.